# Setting images from url in ViewPager Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/10/image-gallery-by-viewpager-android.html) for implementing `ViewPager` in my project. I have done that using **static images** successfully. Now I want to change it so that images are retrieved from **urls** and displayed in `ViewPager`. Below is my code.

> Where should I add the method for downloading images and how to set it
>   to my `ViewPager`?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<Integer> images;
    private BitmapFactory.Options options;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private View btnNext, btnPrev;
    private FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter;
    private LinearLayout thumbnailsContainer;
    private final static int[] resourceIDs = new int[]{R.mipmap.a, R.mipmap.b,
            R.mipmap.c, R.mipmap.d, R.mipmap.e, R.mipmap.f, R.mipmap.g};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        images = new ArrayList<>();

        //find view by id
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        thumbnailsContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        btnNext = findViewById(R.id.next);
        btnPrev = findViewById(R.id.prev);

        btnPrev.setOnClickListener(onClickListener(0));
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(onClickListener(1));

        setImagesData();

        // init viewpager adapter and attach
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), images);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        inflateThumbnails();
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener(final int i) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    //next page
                    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() < viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    //previous page
                    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() > 0) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void setImagesData() {
        for (int i = 0; i < resourceIDs.length; i++) {
            images.add(resourceIDs[i]);
        }
    }

    private void inflateThumbnails() {
        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            View imageLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_image, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.img_thumb);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(onChagePageClickListener(i));
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
            options.inDither = false;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), images.get(i), options );
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            //set to image view
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            //add imageview
            thumbnailsContainer.addView(imageLayout);
        }
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onChagePageClickListener(final int i) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**PageFragment class:**

```
   public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

        private int imageResource;
        private Bitmap bitmap;

        public static PageFragment getInstance(int resourceID) {
            PageFragment f = new PageFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("image_source", resourceID);
            f.setArguments(args);
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            imageResource = getArguments().getInt("image_source");
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inSampleSize = 4;
            o.inDither = false;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageResource, o);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = null;
        }
    }

ViewPager Adapter class:

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Integer> images;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Integer> imagesList) {
        super(fm);
        this.images = imagesList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.getInstance(images.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to download image from url?

Comment: Yes. I have an array of image urls. I meant i want to set images from those urls not download.

Comment: @Jas basically you want to set default image from those urls whom you failed to get image ?

Comment: No. the tutorial i got was for displaying images from my drawables folder. Now i want to change it to the images i download from url

Comment: Can i simply use asynctask for this and pass the bitmap to my ViewPager?

Comment: Why to do things which already available. Check this [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To use **ViewPager** for images you have to make a adapter which extends **PagerAdapter** like as below:

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(arrayList != null){
            return arrayList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_viewpager_layout, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerItem_image1);

        Picasso.with(context).load(arrayList.get(position))
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.image_uploading)
                            .error(R.drawable.image_not_found).into(imageView);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

}
```

And `xml` layout for adapter is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerItem_image1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

For Download Images from `URL` you have to use `AsyncTask`.

For that follow below Example of DownloadImageFromAsyncTask.

```
new LoadImage().execute("http://www.sumtrix.com/images/sumtrix/Android-Wallpaper-HD.jpg");
```

Set your url to above url.

```
private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading Image...");
            dialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(params[0]).getContent());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if (result != null) {
                img.setImageBitmap(result);
                dialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Does Not Exist...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
```

for that you have to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Please check my classes and provide an answer as per my requirement

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used Picasso to make it simple

Answer (score 1):

IMO you should set your image here, your `imageResource` is your `imgUrl` and using a lib such as: `UniversalImageLoader`, `Volley`, `Picasso`... we have many libs to support loading image with url.

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inSampleSize = 4;
        o.inDither = false;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageResource, o);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used Picasso to make it simple

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to download and show on imageView.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_here);
        new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
            .execute("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png");
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, IndexActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

add internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

see this [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20120802025411/http://developer.aiwgame.com/imageview-show-image-from-url-on-android-4-0.html) for more detail

Comment: Please check my classes and help me by providing an answer as per my requirement

Comment: @Jas we will not write code for you here, we will guide u how to do one particular task, you have to understand and implement according to your requirement. In order to use url in imageViews, first you have to create an arraylist of image url, pass it to above asynctask with respective imageView, it will download the image first and then show on ImageView automatically. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used Picasso to make it simple

Answer (score 1):

I use Picasso library when I need to show image from a URL. It is extremely simple to use.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

    Picasso.with(this)
        .load(image_url)
        .into(imageView);
}
```

You can see references and download library from this, [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) 
Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you should call the picdownloadertask  in onViewCreated()

```
    @Override
            public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
               new PicDownladerTask().execute(url)


            }
```

class PicDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask {

```
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(strings[0]);
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
               BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inSampleSize = 4;
            o.inDither = false;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageResource, o);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
```

this is the method to get images from url

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(70000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(70000);

            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
//            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
//            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
//            os.close();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            conn.disconnect();
//            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError){}
//                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Jas To make things simpler. you always use libraries like (okhttp and picasso ) or (ion) which well accepted  among developers. then the pocess of downloading and showing the image comes into 1 line of code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used Picasso to make it simple

Comment: @Jas that will definitly reduce the work. Since problem is solved and almost all the answers are correct. Accept one and close the question

Answer (score 1):

create a async task and download the image in do in background

```
@Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {
        this.url = url[0];
        final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet getRequest = new org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet(
                url[0]);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                LoggerUtils.logWarn("ImageDownloader", "Error "
                        + statusCode + " while retrieving bitmap from "
                        + url[0]);
                return null;
            }
            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = entity.getContent();

                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                            .decodeStream(inputStream);
                    return bitmap;
                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getRequest.abort();

        }
```